# Understanding for loops, very simple

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am an absolute beginner in c++, and I find my biggest confusion to be about loops. (and arrays, but thats a whole different story)... Anyways, I was wondering how the output for the following code is figured out. Of course I have run it, and I get -1 1 3 5 7 6. I have been trying to go through the loop to figure out why it is outputting that but I have had no luck. Can you please explain each step and how each number is gotten? Thank you.

```
int main()
{
int num = 0;
    int count;
    int y = 0;
    for (count = 1; count <= 5; ++count)
    {
        num = 3 * (count - 1) + (y - count);
        cout << num << " ";
    }
    cout << count << " " << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "_Can you please explain each step and how each number is gotten?_" This is **the** perfect task to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: Try printing just the value of `count` in the loop. Then plug in your equation to calculate `num`. It should be possible to map out the values on a piece of paper. It’s only 5 iterations.

Comment: Take `num = 3 * (count - 1) + (y - count);` and substitute `count` with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and calculate the `num`. The last `6` is the last increment of `count` that didn't satisfy loop condition and it got aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Many, if not most, programming languages are step by step instructions to be executed by a computer.

If you want to know what happens, you have to follow this stream of instructions.

---

A [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) has these parts:

1. Initialization of the index/counter variable: `count = 1`
2. Check the loop condition: `count <= 5`
3. Execute the loop body:

   ```
   num = 3 * (count - 1) + (y - count);
   cout << num << " ";`
   ```
4. Final iteration expression (frequently a counter variable increment): `++count`

---

Now do the steps manually on a piece of paper.

- Start with `count = 1`
- Check if `count` is less than or equal to five
- As long as it is, calculate `num` by plugging the variables into the formula
- Write the result on the paper
- Finally continue with the next iteration, `++count`, and go back to the check